# Page Control Navigation Symbol?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipagecontrol

Could someone point me in the right direction on how you get your Page Controller to show the navigation symbol like this?

[image: Page Control with Current Location]

I couldn't really describe it well, and couldn't find much relevant information on the internet. Anything would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a custom UIPageController.

Or you might be able to add a UIImageView to the left of the page control and when you try to swipe, set that image view to highlighted and you'll get the same effect.

Here's a custom page control, DDPageControl

https://github.com/ddeville/DDPageControl